# No sound on my ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, intel, hda-intel

i have installed Ubuntu 22.04LTS and my audio chipset is Intel Icelake. There is no audio.
Please help me.i'm attaching a image [alsamixer command on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr9W6.png)

Comment: Have you selected the correct audio output device? Please [edit] the question and add details about your setup.

Comment: How can i select my audio output device?

Comment: At system settings.

Comment: I tested dummy output no sound at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```